# How to pass a different value than the end-of-stream default constructed istream_iterator?

Tags: c++

1) How can I pass a different value than *end-of-stream* to functions like `find_if()`, `sort()`, or `for_each()`?

I don't manage to handle iterators, especially to use them in loops, it seems the way I try to browse the values is improper. What I'm trying to do with this code is to input some numbers with `cin`, to extract the even numbers with `find_if`, but to print the first three with `for_each` or any loop using those iterators. If I use another kind, there would be no purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
typedef istream_iterator<int> IIT;

int main()
{
    IIT iter(cin);
    IIT eos;
    auto even = [](int i){ return (i%2==0); };
    iter = find_if(iter, eos, even);
    //iter = find_if(iter, IIT(), even); //also works, it seems that ctor call of "IIT eof()" wasn't equivalent


    //auto print = [](IIT i){ cout << *i << " "; };
    //auto print = [](IIT i){ cout << *i << " "; return i; };
    //auto print = [](IIT i){ cout << *i << " "; return 0; };  //I don't know what I'm doing
    auto print = [](IIT i)->int { cout << *i << " "; return 0; };  //this doesn't help

    for_each(iter,eos,print); //no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(IIT)>) (const int&)'|

    for_each<IIT,IIT>(iter,eos,print); //no matching function for call to 'for_each(IIT&, IIT&, main()::<lambda(IIT)>&)'|
                                       //cannot convert 'print' (type 'main()::<lambda(IIT)>') to type 'std::istream_iterator<int>'|

    for(auto i : iter) cout << *i << " ";  //candidate: template<class _Tp, unsigned int _Nm> constexpr _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])|
                                           //template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
                                           //mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'std::istream_iterator<int>'|
    return 0;
}
```

[end-of-stream iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

> The default-constructed std::istream_iterator is known as the
>   end-of-stream iterator. When a valid std::istream_iterator reaches the
>   end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream
>   iterator.

[istream_iterator : default constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/)

> Constructs an end-of-stream istream iterator." [..] This kind of iterator has a special state as an end-of-stream iterator, which is
>   acquired if an input operations fails (as returned by fail after an
>   operation with the associated stream), and is also the resulting value
>   of a default-constructed object.

`stl_algo.h`

```
  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Function>
    _Function
    for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
      __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    __f(*__first);
      return _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `std::for_each` has template arguments `template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >`
   You are calling it like so: `for_each<IIT, IIT>`.

   Change this to `for_each<IIT, decltype(print)>` if you wish to use explicit template arguments (although I recommend letting the compiler infer the args via the parameters)
2. Your `print` function is accepting an `IIT`, when in fact algorithms will dereference the iterators passed to it for the unary function, so it should accept an `int` instead:

   ```
   auto print = [](int i)->int { cout << i << " "; return 0; };
   ```
3. `for(auto i : iter)` makes no sense; `iter` is an iterator type, not a range.